# Serializing private members with protobuf-net for windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize a simple custom class that has private members, using [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Extensions) library, for a windows store style app:

```
[ProtoContract]
class ProtoTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string Test;

    public ProtoTest(string test)
    {
        this.Test = test;
    }        
}
```

When I serialize an instance the private member is never serialized but is instead ignored. Making the member public resolves the problem but is not really a satisfactory solution for my application. Is there anything that I'm doing incorrectly here or does anybody know if this is a known bug (I did search but couldn't find anything)?

Answer (score 0):

The sample in the [protobuf-net wiki](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Extensions).

```
 [ProtoContract]
    public class StandaloneExtensible : IExtensible
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int KnownField { get; set; }

        private byte[] buffer;
        Stream IExtensible.BeginAppend() {
            return Extensible.BeginAppend();
        }
        Stream IExtensible.BeginQuery() {
            return Extensible.BeginQuery(buffer);
        }
        void IExtensible.EndAppend(Stream stream, bool commit) {
            buffer = Extensible.EndAppend(buffer, stream, commit);
        }
        void IExtensible.EndQuery(Stream stream) {
            Extensible.EndQuery(stream);
        }
        int IExtensible.GetLength() {
            return Extensible.GetLength(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whilst I might be able to use an extension to work around the problem this does not really provide an adequate solution. Whenever I've used the protobuf-net library on any other platform (Windows / Mono / Xamarin.Android / Xamarin.iOS) I've always been able to serialize private members. Do you know if this is a fundamental limitation of Windows Store Applications that prevents private members being serialized?

Comment: If you used it in Windows there shouldn't be any limitations. Is it the same version? Personally, I didn't worked with this library before.